# Does puppeteer press Win + PrtSc to take screenshot?

Tags: javascript, web, puppeteer, screenshot

Currently I'm programming to automate screenshot. I've learnt websites cannot detect if users screenshot or not, however they can know the key stroke we typed. So, I'd like to know when puppeteer screenshots using `page.screenshot();` websites can detect Win + PrtSc keys.

I tried to screenshot on [text](https://en.key-test.ru/) but it didn't show the keys, but not sure if it's not expected way to press keys or `page.screenshot()` taking screenshots without pressing keys.

Comment: 1. No. It just take a screenshot. That would be like asking if the way for a software to print a file is to emulate "Ctrl+P". 
2. No, websites have no keylogger on your PC. That would be the awfullest security failure imaginable. They only know about the keys you press while the focus in on their page. And even among those, only those that the OS decided may concern them. If you were typing `Win+PrtScr` to take a screenshot (which pupeteer isn't), while the website window has the focus, they will get the even on `Win`, but not `PrtScr`.

Answer (score 0):

No, Puppeteer doesn't use Win + PrtSc keys to take a screenshot. Programs don't generally issue keystrokes--they call a function in the operating system's (OS) application programming interface (API) directly.

But Puppeteer doesn't primarily interface with OS APIs, it uses the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) (CDP). [`Page.captureScreenshot`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) is the lower-level CDP screenshot call made by Puppeteer. You can see it in the source in [src/cdp/Page.ts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/197f00547ea402118c7db3cfaa4a57eb0efdd4cc/packages/puppeteer-core/src/cdp/Page.ts#L1093):

```js
const {data} = await this.#primaryTargetClient.send(
  'Page.captureScreenshot',
  {
    format: type,
    ...(optimizeForSpeed ? {optimizeForSpeed} : {}),
    ...(quality !== undefined ? {quality: Math.round(quality)} : {}),
    ...(clip ? {clip: {...clip, scale: clip.scale ?? 1}} : {}),
    ...(!fromSurface ? {fromSurface} : {}),
    captureBeyondViewport,
  }
);
```

For comparison, Playwright has similar code in [crPage.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/36eed69fe28e9556395f209a92b66bebe699a28b/packages/playwright-core/src/server/chromium/crPage.ts#L286):

```js
const result = await this._mainFrameSession._client.send(
  "Page.captureScreenshot",
  {format, quality, clip, captureBeyondViewport: !fitsViewport}
);
```

Don't worry about the details here--libraries like Puppeteer can be complex, since they're doing a lot of heavy lifting to make the lower-level CDP calls simple for application programming. If CDP was easy to use directly by application programmers, there'd be no need for wrappers like Puppeteer and Playwright.

`Page.captureScreenshot` could be thought of as a programmatic version of [taking a screenshot using the browser DevTools](https://www.howtogeek.com/423558/how-to-take-full-page-screenshots-in-google-chrome-without-using-an-extension/) as a human user, rather than taking a screenshot with Windows.

You might next ask "how does Chrome capture a screenshot?" which I can't fully answer, since I'm not familiar with browser engine programming or its APIs. But at a high level, the [browser engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_engine), which is responsible for rendering a web page, understands the position, style and content of the elements on the page based on the page's HTML and CSS, and can translate these elements into a series of pixels that represent image data.

At no point is the screenshot capability of the operating system involved, and certainly not the OS keyboard API. Theoretically, you could automate a browser using something like [RobotJS](https://robotjs.io/) which does issue programmatic OS keyboard and mouse commands, but this would be very brittle and [Rube Goldbergian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg#/media/File:Rube_Goldberg%27s_%22Self-Operating_Napkin%22_(cropped).gif). You'd have to know the button positions for the browser! Getting a clean full-page screenshot would be extremely difficult with a pure OS keyboard API.